# Subprocess: Execute two or more preexec_fn

Tags: python, function, call, subprocess

I was wondering if there is a way of creating a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (through `subprocess.Popen`) that calls secuentially two (or more) `preexec_fn`.

For instance, calling `setegid` and `seteuid` (just for example purposes).

So far, I found this workaround (and well... it works, but it doesn't look too... direct or "clean")

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import subprocess
import os

def preExecuter(listOfFunctions):
    for functionEntry in listOfFunctions:
        functionEntry["function"](* functionEntry.get("args", []), **functionEntry.get("kwargs", {}))


listOfFunctions = [
    {
        "function": os.setegid,
        "args": [1000],
    },
    {
        "function": os.seteuid,
        "args": [1000],
    },
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sp = subprocess.Popen(["whoami"], preexec_fn=preExecuter(listOfFunctions))
    sp.communicate()
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about...

```
   subprocess.Popen( ..., preexec_fn = lambda : ( os.setegid(1000), os.seteuid(1000)) )
```

... presumably the return value from  the function is discarded...

Comment: Assuming the second call is not "seteuid(1000)" but "os.seteuid(1000), this is the closest thing to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

That's not even going to work, since the call to preExecuter actually executes the setegid and seteuid operations, and is done before Popen is called. What's wrong with

```
def my_pre_exec() :
    os.setegid(1000)
    os.seteuid(1000)


subprocess.Popen( ..., preexec_fn = my_pre_exec )
```

Comment: Well... the thing is that I wanted a more "generic" way; creating a function to accept several pre-exec functions

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a generic way to defer function calls:

```
def defer_call_to( func, *parms, **kwparms ):
    def caller():
        func( *parms, **kwparms)
    return caller
```

now you can do

```
subprocess.Popen( ..., preexec_fn = defer_call_to( os.set_gid, 1000))
```

... since defer_call_to returns a function does the deferred call when called.

If you want more than one, this will now work properly:

```
   sp = subprocess.Popen(["whoami"], preexec_fn=defer_call_to( preExecuter,listOfFunctions))
```

But, it's cleaner to just write a function as in my other answer

Comment: Not so happy with this answer now, since this is basically what lambda functions are for...  preexec_fn = lambda : preExecuter(listOfFunctions))